# Django redirecting from unknown reason

Tags: django, python-2.7, redirect

I was working on this app some time back and I have returned and for the life of me cannot see where a redirection is occurring.

From starting the app as below and navigating to the base URL, you can see attempt to reach '/Sites/' url

```
python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 20, 2018 - 16:35:05
Django version 1.11.13, using settings 'SysMan.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Not Found: /Sites/
[20/Jun/2018 16:35:07] "GET /Sites/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2263
```

The urls file is as below.

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
admin.site.site_header = 'Rio System Management'
admin.site.site_title = 'Rio SysMan admin'
admin.site.index_title = 'SysMan Administration'
urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/main/', permanent=True)),
     url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
     url(r'^main/', include('apps.main.urls')),
     url(r'^asnreg/', include('apps.asnreg.urls')),
]
```

I have run grep against the project folders for `Sites` with nothing of meaning being returned there.

Manually browsing to the URL's as below get me where I need to be.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/asnreg/
```

Just can't figure why

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

redirects me to

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/Sites/
```

I have looked at the various views file with nothing obvious there either

- I did copy/paste the folders into a new virtenv. Could something be lingering in the DB??

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache of your browser or using incognito mode?

Comment: @Burhan Khalid, bloody Firefox cache :) . It must be at least 6 month since I worked this, so did not even enter my mind. Thanks.